# functional programming - call function with all parameters

Tags: php, parameters, functional-programming

I'm actually experimenting the functional programming in php. I would like to have some precisions about some function calls.

as an example:

```
function addition($num1){
    return function ($num2) use ($num1){
        return $num1+$num2;
    }
}
$add_2_to = addition(2);
echo $add_2_to(3);
echo $add_2_to(4);
```

Is there a way to call the addition function with all the parameters?
I tried in this way with no chances:

```
echo addition(2)(3);
```

Comment: ps that is multiplication (using `*`), not addition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are pretty close. PHP doesn't have lexical scope so the variable $num1 is not available within the returned function... for that you have to explicitly import it using `use`

```
function addition($num1){
    return function ($num2) use ($num1){
        return $num1*$num2;
    };
}
$add_2_to = addition(2);
echo $add_2_to(3);
echo $add_2_to(4);
```

The syntax you proposed `echo addition(2)(3);` currently will not work but when php 7 arrives it will. For current versions of php you can use call_user_func to do what you want.

```
echo call_user_func(addition(2), 3);
```